# Relative positioned block shows nonexistent right margin

Tags: html, css, css-position

**Brief question**: Click the first link below and explain me why Chrome shows margin on the right, if it doesn't have any.

**Long question**:

I'd like to understand why Google Chrome shows different graphical representations from absolute and relative positioned blocks.

On an absolute positioned block, Chrome shows the element the way I've expected.

On an relative positioned block, the element's width shows something more. It looks like some margin or padding, but I zeroed the paddings and margins from this div and it still looks the same on Chrome Inspect Tools.

Look how the relative div has an "extension" to its width.

[inspected relative div screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxEK.png)

And here, the absolute div doesn't have this "extension".

[inspected absolute div screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcDC.png)

And here's a code where this can be demonstrated.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

.absolute-class, .relative-class {
display: block;
width: 100px;
left: 20px;
font-size: 24px;
}

.absolute-class {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
}

.relative-class {
position: relative;
top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="absolute-class">Text 1</div>
        <div class="relative-class">Text 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm worried about this, because I think this extra "margin" is causing an horizontal scrolling on the page I am developing. So I would like to understand what this is, to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: _"I'm worried about this, because I think this extra "margin" is causing an horizontal scrolling on the page I am developing"_ - it's not - set `overflow:auto` for the wrapper div, then it would show scroll bars if the relative positioned element actually was stretching that far - but it doesn't, so whatever actual problem you are trying to solve, is likely not reflected in this code.

Comment: That looks like an auto right margin. You can see a similar phantom margin if you inspect the wrapper div. What's really strange is that Chrome doesn't recalculate this auto right margin if you specify a left margin on the relatively positioned div alongside the width - it still calculates the auto right margin as though the left margin were auto (which is zeroed out on the left side) while simultaneously displaying whatever left margin you specify. I haven't the faintest clue why Chrome is doing this, but it's Chrome, so I'm not surprised that it's pulling weird shenanigans such as this.

Comment: @CBroe yes, you are right. I tried to reproduce the scrolling by doing what you've said, and it really didn't show any scroll. But on my real project, it does affect the scroll. I just didn't isolate the problem enough to bring it here. So I just came here to ask what is this *phantom margin*.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes! I've seen this phantom margin on the wrapper div too! You really understood my question. But why does a relative positioned element has this auto right margin? Does it need to always fill all the width of the container?

Comment: @Rodolfo Ferraz: A relatively positioned block box is still in the flow, which means that other boxes also in the flow will be affected by the relative box's margins. Auto margins behave the same on relative block boxes as non-positioned block boxes. Having said that, since it's an auto margin, it shouldn't be causing scrollbars since the width of the element itself isn't overflowing the wrapper.

Comment: @BoltClock I see. I understand all what you've said, but I still don't understand why it still shows this auto margin, if I set margin to zero. Shouldn't this auto margin disappear?

Comment: @Rodolfo Ferraz: Beats me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes outside the div because you give `left:20px` and set the fixed width, so left will push your div to outside the wrapper div. Use `padding-left:20px;`

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

.absolute-class, .relative-class {
display: block;
width: 100px;
padding-left: 20px;
font-size: 24px;
}

.absolute-class {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
}

.relative-class {
position: relative;
top: 30px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="absolute-class">Text 1</div>
        <div class="relative-class">Text 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or you can also use `display: inline-block;` in `.relative-class`

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}

.absolute-class, .relative-class {
display: block;
width: 100px;
left: 20px;
font-size: 24px;
}

.absolute-class {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
}

.relative-class {
position: relative;
top: 30px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="absolute-class">Text 1</div>
        <div class="relative-class">Text 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably padding-left will solve my problem, thanks. But it doesn't answer the question. If you remove `display: inline-block` from `.relative-class` it still shows this _extra margin_ to the **right**. I just want to know what this is. Chrome Inspect Tools doesn't show any numbers defined in margin-right, so I know it isn't a margin, but what is it?

Comment: please check the first image again. I've replaced it for one that shows how Chrome considers this extra width as **margin**.

Comment: This is an auto margin because you have given 300px width to wrapper and 100px width to text div. So, when you use position relative it takes full 300px width. It covers 100px as you given for text and other space is shown as default margin because it is empty. And when you give left 20px then it push the div outside 20px of wrapper. So, it looks like outside  the div because it maintains total width of 300px.

Comment: If you want to solve it then use display:inline-block; in .relative-class. Because when you add inline-block it only takes that space in which it is.

Comment: I will accept your answer, since it solved my problem. I used `padding-left` as you suggested. I still can't really understand this auto-margin behavior (it keeps showing margin, even if you zero it), but maybe this is a subject for another question. You helped me to narrow and describe better my doubt here.